# How to Compare two Qstrings?

Tags: c++, qt, string-comparison, qstring

I have to compare two Qstrings in qt,

say,

```
Qstring str1="1005",str2="1006";
```

I have tried using ,

```
if(str1==str2){
   return true;
}
```

&

```
if(str1.compare(str2)==0)
{
    return true;
}
```

still both methods goes inside if condition &  returns true.

Comment: Yes, I have checked the same in debugging mode and surprisingly it was going inside the if condition.

Comment: How about an SSCCE? In particular, show what your function is supposed to return when the strings aren't equal.

Comment: You actually mean `QString`, right? Please try to provide an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) we could just paste into a file and build.

Comment: Do you want to compare for equality? If so, what is the problem with `==`?

Comment: I couldn't reproduce it. Are you sure you didn't modify any of them in between declaring and comparing? And is `Qstring` is just a typo or you have a custom type named exactly `Qstring`?

Comment: This question is about a problem caused by a stale build. The answer won't help anyone else, since the problem is *not* with the code. It's off topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It worked after Rebuilding the Project , I think this is the problem with QT CREATOR

Comment: This doesn't answer how to compare two QT strings. It seemly shows that you had some temporary environment problems.

Comment: @Maxim It doesnt mean that u'll downvote.I have posted here because I was not able to figure out the weird behavior of Qt. But if it got solved by fixing some environment related issue then it is my responsibility to let people know that it was my fault & close this thread.

Comment: @Maxim is correct. This answer is not useful. Hence the downvotes.

Comment: Not an answer, but might have been included as an update to the question

Answer (score 53):

You can use :

```
int x = QString::compare(str1, str2, Qt::CaseInsensitive);  // if strings are equal x should return 0
```

Comment: Although the question asks how to compare strings, that's not *really* what it's asking since the question already demonstrates two ways of comparing strings, including the one suggested in this answer. The question means to ask why the comparisons appear to evaluate to unexpected results. Case sensitivity isn't involved in the example given.

Comment: Third parameter can be changed according to how you want to compare them. I just gave an example of comparing strings.

Comment: But the OP already has two examples of how to compare strings in his question, both of which are correct. So that is not the problem.

Comment: btw ur code is invalid because QString::compare isn't static, so u cannot use it as u wrote, it should be: int x = str1.compare(str2);

Answer (score 17):

The code below works fine for me.

```
int main(int argv, char **args)
 {
    QString str1="1005",str2="1006";
    if(str1 == str2)
        qDebug()<<"This should not print";
    qDebug()<<"Everything Ok";

}
```

Output:

```
Everything Ok
```

The `==` operator is overloaded for QStrings, [as documented here](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#operator-eq-eq-1).

I don't know why your code is not working. Recheck other parts of your code.